# Does Visual Source Support SVN-like Post Commit Hooks?

Tags: svn, deployment, version-control, visual-sourcesafe, svn-hooks

I am forced to use Visual Source Safe at my current job. Yes I know, It's like a stick in the eye. But VSS won't go away, VSS is here to stay.

I was wondering if there is any way to do something similar to Subversion's Post-Commit hooks in VSS? Coupled with a few deployment scripts, this would make our lives much, much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are [hooks for Visual Source Safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509341%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (with examples in Visual Basic 5).
If I were you I'd stay away from this. Your situation is bad enough.
If you still want to implement hooks I believe that what you are looking for is the [AfterCheckIn event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509341%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#vssauto_topic6).

Comment: In my case, VSS is long gone, but this is the right answer. Unfortunately it is client side only. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  You might be able to get something like that with a third party provider like Source Offsite or something (google it).

If VSS is "here to stay" at your company, then I think you have some bigger issues to deal with over there than just VSS, especially since you can get everything you need for source control for $0.00 with SVN.

Comment: Yeah, I think the long term goal is to move to TFS, but I don't see it happening any time soon :(

Comment: @ByronWhitlock May the force be with you and may god have mercy on your poor soul. Moving to TFS is an improvement but it's still not a good VCS unless you plug Git into it.